# GCP - can billing be configured at the folder level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

Please help understand what it means "Configure the billing account the project folder level in the resource hierarchy" statement. According to [Architecting with Google Kubernetes Engine: Foundations Week 1 Introduction to Google Cloud](https://www.coursera.org/learn/foundations-google-kubernetes-engine-gke/exam/pnSel/introduction-to-google-cloud), configuring the billing account is possible at the folder level.

[image]

However, according to [Overview of Cloud Billing concepts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts), it should be at the project level.

[image]

The same coursera [Billing](https://www.coursera.org/learn/foundations-google-kubernetes-engine-gke/lecture/bMzL6/billing) section also mentions the billing is at project levels.

> Link your billing account to one or more projects.Projects you don't link to any billing account can only use free Google Cloud services.Your billing account can be charged automatically and invoice every month, or at every threshold limit.

Comment: I believe it's just a low-quality question, or might be they do this intentionally to simulate ambiguity in real-world life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can associated a Google Billing Account with a GCP organization or GCP Projects.  There is no concept of associating a billing account with a folder.

Here is the Google [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts) that explains billing accounts:

I think you referenced that in the original question.  If you have found a reference or quote that points to some concept of associating a billing account with a folder, I'd suggest that to be an error and probably want to report it to the party that owns the reference.